# How to create a NSMutableDictionary using dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: method

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want create and return a dictionary using the keys and values found in a file specified by a given path.  I have my file on my Desktop:ciudades.txt (a human readable file!!! no a xml, just for practice). What method of my NSString i need to use and how? Please can somebody help me filling on my code the XXXXXXX. Thanks in advance

```
- (NSMutableDictionary)ciudades
{
    if (!ciudades) {
        NSString *path = [NSString XXXXXXXXX];
        ciudades = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add that file to your application bundle By adding a existing file from xcode to your project. Then use this method to get the file path for example I'm getting a image's path.

```
NSString *path   = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imageName ofType:@"png"];
```

then try the dictionaryWithContentsOfFile method and see if it works or not.

Answer (score 1):

Define a function.

```
-(NSMutableDictionary*) ReadFileAsDictionaryForPath:(NSString* ) path
    {
        return [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
    }
```

Use it as below

```
NSString *path   = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyFile" ofType:@"txt"];
NSMutableDictionary* myDictionary = [self ReadFileAsDictionaryForPath:path];

if(!myDictionary)
{
  NSLog(@"Error while reading data from file at path:%@",path);
}
```